# How to add a radiobutton to select a row with ant design table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to add an extra column to this ant table, the column should have a radio button to select the active row.

Only one row can be selected at a time, and when selected I need to call a rest api with at least the ID of the selected client.

In antd documentation I cant find something similar.
https://ant.design/components/table/

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  Table} from 'antd';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';


class ListTenants extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    }



    fetchData = () => {
        adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Tenant", {})
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
            if (!this.isCancelled) {
                const results= responseJson.map(row => ({
                    key: row.ClientId,
                    ClientId: row.ClientId,
                    ClientSecret: row.ClientSecret,
                    Id: row.Id,
                    SiteCollectionTestUrl: row.SiteCollectionTestUrl,
                    TenantDomainUrl: row.TenantDomainUrl
                  }))
              this.setState({ data: results });
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };


    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }

    render() {
        const columns = [
                {
                    title: 'Client Id',
                    dataIndex: 'ClientId',
                    key: 'ClientId'
                }, 
                {
                    title: 'Site Collection TestUrl',
                    dataIndex: 'SiteCollectionTestUrl',
                    key: 'SiteCollectionTestUrl',
                },
                {
                    title: 'Tenant DomainUrl',
                    dataIndex: 'TenantDomainUrl',
                    key: 'TenantDomainUrl',
                }
        ];



        return (
            <Table columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.data} />
        );
    }
}

export default ListTenants;
```

any guidance in how to do this is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  Table, Radio} from 'antd';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';
import Notification from '../../components/notification';

class ListTenants extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    }



    fetchData = () => {
        adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Tenant", {})
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
            if (!this.isCancelled) {
                const results= responseJson.map(row => ({
                    key: row.ClientId,
                    ClientId: row.ClientId,
                    ClientSecret: row.ClientSecret,
                    Id: row.Id,
                    SiteCollectionTestUrl: row.SiteCollectionTestUrl,
                    TenantDomainUrl: row.TenantDomainUrl
                  }))
              this.setState({ data: results });
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };


    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }

    render() {
        const columns = [
                {
                    title: 'Client Id',
                    dataIndex: 'ClientId',
                    key: 'ClientId'
                }, 
                {
                    title: 'Site Collection TestUrl',
                    dataIndex: 'SiteCollectionTestUrl',
                    key: 'SiteCollectionTestUrl',
                },
                {
                    title: 'Tenant DomainUrl',
                    dataIndex: 'TenantDomainUrl',
                    key: 'TenantDomainUrl',
                }
        ];

        // rowSelection object indicates the need for row selection
        const rowSelection = {
            onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
                if(selectedRows[0].key != undefined){
                    console.log(selectedRows[0].key);


                    const options = { 
                        method: 'post', 
                        body: JSON.stringify({ clientid : selectedRows[0].key.toString() }) ,
                        config: {
                            headers: {
                              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            }
                          }
                    };

                    adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Tenant/SetTenantActive", options)
                        .then(response =>{
                        if(response.status === 200){
                            Notification(
                                'success',
                                'Tenant set to active',
                                ''
                                );
                        }else{
                            throw "error";
                        }
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                        Notification(
                            'error',
                            'Tenant not activated',
                            error
                            );
                        console.error(error);
                    });
                }
            },
            getCheckboxProps: record => ({
                type: Radio
            }),
        };

        return (
            <Table rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.data} />
        );
    }
}

export default ListTenants;
```

basically the const rowselection, has a property getCheckboxProps to set either radio or checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

just simple user table like this

```html
<Table rowSelection={{type:'radio'}} >...</Table>
```